# Elasticsearch on multiple fields with partial and full matches

Tags: elasticsearch

Our `Account` model has a `first_name`, `last_name` and a `ssn` (social security number).

I want to do partial matches on the `first_name,`last_name' but an exact match on `ssn`. I have this so far:

```
settings analysis: {
    filter: {
      substring: {
        type: "nGram",
        min_gram: 3,
        max_gram: 50
      },
      ssn_string: {
        type: "nGram",
        min_gram: 9,
        max_gram: 9
      },
    },
    analyzer: {
      index_ngram_analyzer: {
        type: "custom",
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter: ["lowercase", "substring"]
      },
      search_ngram_analyzer: {
        type: "custom",
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter:  ["lowercase", "substring"]
      },
      ssn_ngram_analyzer: {
        type: "custom",
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter: ["ssn_string"]
      },
     }
   }

   mapping do
    [:first_name, :last_name].each do |attribute|
      indexes attribute, type: 'string', 
                         index_analyzer: 'index_ngram_analyzer',
                         search_analyzer: 'search_ngram_analyzer'
   end

   indexes :ssn, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

  end
```

My search is as follows:

```
query: {
  multi_match: {
     fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "ssn"],
     query: query,
     type: "cross_fields",
     operator: "and"
  }
```

}

So this works:

```
 Account.search("erik").records.to_a
```

and even (for Erik Smith):

```
 Account.search("erik smi").records.to_a
```

and the ssn:

```
 Account.search("111112222").records.to_a
```

but not:

```
 Account.search("erik 111112222").records.to_a
```

Any idea if I am indexing or querying wrong?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be done with a single query string? If not, I would do something like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
               "type": "ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": true,
            "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
         },
         "properties": {
            "first_name": {
               "type": "string",
               "include_in_all": true
            },
            "last_name": {
               "type": "string",
               "include_in_all": true
            },
            "ssn": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed",
               "include_in_all": false
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice the use of the[_all field](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html). I included `first_name` and `last_name` in `_all`, but not `ssn`, and `ssn` is not analyzed at all since I want to do exact matches against it.

I indexed a couple of documents for illustration:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"first_name":"Erik","last_name":"Smith","ssn":"111112222"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Jones","ssn":"123456789"}
```

Then I can query for the partial names, and filter by the exact ssn:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "_all": {
                   "query": "eri smi",
                   "operator": "and"
               }
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "ssn": "111112222"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And I get back what I'm expecting:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.8838835,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.8838835,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "Erik",
               "last_name": "Smith",
               "ssn": "111112222"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

If you need to be able to do the search with a single query string (no filter), you could include `ssn` in the `all` field as well, but with this setup it will also match on partial strings (like `111112`) so that may not be what you want.

If you only want to match prefixes (i.e., search terms that start at the beginning of the words), you should use [edge ngrams](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html).

I wrote a blog post about using ngrams which might help you out a little: http://blog.qbox.io/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch

Here is the code I used for this answer. I tried a few different things, including the setup I posted here, and another inluding `ssn` in `_all`, but with edge ngrams. Hope this helps:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/b6a31c929945ef96779c72c468303ea3bc87320f

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply - wow. I will try it out. I think this also worked too: once I took out the `search_analyzer: 'search_ngram_analyzer'`, it is working (so far, with the tests I've done).